# “It’s time you begun” vs. “It’s time you began”

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I noticed that the narrator at the beginning of [Nightmare Before Christmas](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/n/nightmare-before-christmas-script-transcript.html) says, “Now, you’ve probably wondered where holidays come from. / If you haven’t, I’d say it’s time you begun.” ([The intro on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHLgob-PpIk#t=1m10s))

I’m used to subjunctives as in “it’s time you did something” or “it’s time you went there” but not “it’s time you done something” or “it’s time you gone there.” Neither does the “begun” seem to rhyme with anything the way the previous verses do.

What’s going on here?

Comment: You can never trust movie transcription. As [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355933/what-might-go-no-mean) suggests, there are many mistranscribed sentences in movie transcription. Without watching the movie, we can never know what happened exactly. I seriously doubt it was "begun". It must have been "began" and it is a typo.

Comment: There seem to have been quite a few historical examples where 'begun' has been used as simple past. However, [Language Between Description and Prescription: Verbs and Verb Categories in ...
By Lieselotte Anderwald](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DBE9DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22he+begun%22+past+tense&source=bl&ots=7ZP5Pr92B0&sig=Corpide3240Pf42BmdIvqXwn4xU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFwK7Y5P_PAhWHCMAKHQf6AtcQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22he%20begun%22%20past%20tense&f=false) shows that this has long been considered ungrammatical.

Comment: Edwin, interesting, thanks!

Rathony, I noticed it yesterday when watching the movie. I only linked the transcript in case people wanted more context than I had copied into the question. I listened to it twice (to the dismay of my partner), and it sounded clearly like “begun” to me. (But I’m not a native speaker.) I’ll add a YouTube link to the question.

Comment: *begun* does make a near rhyme with *from*, which *began* does not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is likely based on a typo and/or mishearing a word.

Comment: It's not a typo. It's an ungrammatical lyric chosen for the sake of a (near) rhyme with *from*. The lyricist also rhymes *scream* and *Halloween* so to him, /m/ and /n/ must seem acceptably close for near rhymes.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).