# What might "go no" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

There is an episode in Woody Allen's movie *Take the Money and Run*. A lady is being interviewed about Virgil, the main character in the movie. And she goes:

> Just to think that that idiot was a criminal, I just can't believe it. There was a mind working in there that could rob banks. It's phenomenal. Once I said to him, "what do you do?", and he said, "I rob banks". **Go no**, right!

I hope you get the mood of this passage. So, what does this "go no" phrase mean here?

[Here is the episode on youtube](https://youtu.be/6_D8g6XGiB4?t=1h16m3s).

Comment: From the context it looks like it's supposed to mean “go figure”, but it's not an expression I recall ever seeing or hearing before. Are you sure that is in fact what she says? Have you taken the line from the actual script, or have you transcribed it from what you hear when you play the scene?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If it is a transcription, it could be "Go know...", but it still wouldn't make much sense. "No go, right?" would make more sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Both

Comment: It could also be a typo for “go on”, if you read it in subtitles.

Comment: @JonPurdy but I also hear what she is saying :)

Comment: @Mick I think it makes some sense, actually - "go know"

Comment: *Go* is also a synonym for *say*, especially in AmE. The meaning may be 'Say "no", right?' It is possible that some punctuation is omitted in script dialogues.

Comment: There is a strong possibility that **goner** was *mistranscribed* as "go, no". Other than this, I don't have any idea what it would mean. I would have transcribed it as *goner* when I heard a phrase that sounded like "go no".

Answer (score 5):

The transcription of the character should be *Go know, right?*

The subtitles (in Spanish) are *¿Puede creerlo?* "Can you believe it?"

[image: Subtitles from YouTube still]

<sup>Screencap of YouTube subtitles from [*Take the Money and Run*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_D8g6XGiB4)</sup>

The similarity with *Go figure* is useful: that means "Can you work it out?" or "Who would ever have worked that out?" or something similar. In the film, *know* is substituted for *figure*, with a similar construction intended.

Wikipedia mentions *go know* in its [page of Yiddish expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_words_used_in_English):

> geh vays: literally "go know", as in "go figure". ("Last week she said she hated his guts and now she's engaged to him. Geh vays.")

Woody Allen's Jewish heritage is well-known, and apparently* he spoke German at home in his early years. This expression may have rubbed off on him then and appeared in English in later works.

---

* Baxter, John: [*Woody Allen: A Biography*](http://www.adherents.com/people/pa/Woody_Allen.html),  Carroll & Graf Publishers, Inc.: New York (1999), page 11.

Comment: Good sleuthing! Interesting how the correct meaning actually came through even to someone who (like me) didn't actually understand the expression at all and had never heard or seen it before.